# Matlab: Apply a function to a vector

Tags: matlab, function, loops, vectorization

I've had this annoying problem-

What I want to do is  create a line vector that will house in every element a result of a function inside a function WITHOUT USING LOOPS

Instead of using the following code

```
function [ vec_L ] = VecL( N )
%%this function receives an integer number N and returns a vector of N CalcL results  

vec_L = ones(1,N);
for i=1:N
vec_L(i) = CalcL( FairDice(5000) );
end
```

I need a vectorized version to give the same result
where CalcL( FairDice(5000) ) is the function inside a function, and I need to apply the results every time to each element of vec_L

Thanks!

Comment: you should always provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments above, you're trying to find out how many throws it takes to get the same die roll twice.

For a single run of FairDice, our chance of our first repeat occurring on each throw is:

1. 0 [No repeats possible in one throw]
2. 1/6 [1/6 chance that first and second rolls are the same]
3. 5/18 [5/6 chance that first roll and second roll are different, 2/6 chance that third roll is one of these]
4. 5/18 [4/6 * 5/6 chance that first 3 rolls are different, 3/6 chance that fourth roll matches]
5. 5/27 [3/6 * 4/6 * 5/6 chance that first 4 rolls are different, 4/6 chance that fifth roll matches]
6. 25/324 [2/6 * 3/6 * 4/6 * 5/6 chance that first 5 rolls are different, 5/6 chance that sixth roll matches] 25/324
7. 5/324 [1/6 * 2/6 * 3/6 * 4/6 * 5/6 chance that first 6 rolls are different, 1/1 chance that seventh roll matches]

So, we have a probability matrix:

```
probMat = [0 1/6 5/18 5/18 5/27 25/324 5/324];
```

And so we can do the exact same simulation that you're doing by simply testing a random number against the sum of probabilities:

```
randMat = rand(N,1);
[junk, vec_L] = max((cumsumprobMat>randMat),[],2);
```

EDIT: One more way you could use the weighted probabilities is the [randSample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) function:

```
vec_L = randSample(7, N, true, probMat);
```

Comment: that's the theoretic solution, yes, but I need to get closer to it practically, and that's by using the functions I built. my question from the beginning was how could I eliminate the use of 'for', since it is useless when working with very large numbers, and because I do believe that matlab is all about taking a vectorized approach to this kind of problems. Thanks for your time helping!

Comment: I'd disagree that 'for' is useless when working with very large numbers; the improvement of vectorization here is going to be less than the improvement from calling FairDice(7) rather than FairDice(5000).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayfun` to call the function for each input *but* this isn't *really* vectorization, it just removes the `for` loop.

```
vec_L = arrayfun(@()CalcL(FairDice(5000)), 1:N)
```

Keep in mind that there is *no expected performance benefit of this over a for loop*.

You should instead try to vectorize `FairDice` itself so that you can call it once and pass it an array rather than calling `FairDice` `N` times.

Based on the context of your question, all of this seems like it could be replaced with

```
vec_L = randi([1 6], 1, N)
```

Comment: maybe it will be more efficient if I'll explain the context then: 
1) FairDice(k) throws a fair dice k times, and returns a vector with each element representing which number 1-6 we received in each throw
2) CalcL(k) will receive a vector of results from FairDice and will return the number of the first time(throw) in which we received a similar number 1-6, ex I threw 4 times and got 1,3,1,2 so it will return the index  3. So I need for each element of the vec_L to house a different result of the 2 functions. Thanks again!

Comment: @RomanAndreevitchBiriukov So you want to find the location of the first second occurrence of a number?

Comment: exactly, and I need to run this on every element of vec_L, basically get a different result every time, and make a vector out of it

Comment: Why would you run it to FairDice(5000) then? You only need FairDice(7) to guarantee a repeat